# Wired sensor bus technology

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, bus, serial-bus, modbus

I am working on a project which requires a dozen VL53l0X I2C-TOF sensors to be polled by one master MCU over a few meters of cable.

Thus, I decided to accompany each TOF by an Atmega8 acting as a gateway between the TOF and a Modbus (using a MAX485), which is managed by an ESP32 (the master). Since I require fairly low latency (~10 reads / sensor / second) I am a bit disappointed by the Modbus RTU performance (mostly caused by the forced 1.75ms delay between frames).

My question: Is there any quicker, more suitable, Atmega-bearable bus protocol for long distances? Ethernet is sadly not an option due to the limited slaves computing power and cost...

Comment: It sounds like you have a protocol problem, not a physical layer problem.  Eg have the master send a fake "sensor 0" message at which point the first helper does a reading and sends it as "sensor 1".  The second helper triggers off the first, and so on.  You could even introduce a pipeline delay of doing your local reading a few steps before sending it.

Comment: Sure, I could implement my own protocol like you described. Although keeping the advantages of something like modbus would be awesome, of course. Also, I was not worrying about the physical layer. I was just hoping to find some already established protocol with addressing, error detection, different message types etc...

Comment: Why mega8? The esp32 is a similar cost to the avr and 485chip. I’d consider having a esp32 on each node and you’ll have bandwidth to spare. If you’re really cost conscious then use esp8266. You can network time sync if you want and a webpage on each node!

Comment: The ESP32 is worrying me because of space and power consumption...also, am I getting it right that the ESP32 doesn't output the two differential can lines? So, I'd need another driver chip anyway...

Comment: Run wifi. Much higher bandwidth than CAN. If you realky want wired, then bolt on a CAN transceiver. Unless you’re building zillions, the extra $$ for the esp32 is dwarfed by the vl sensor cost, pcb,  assy and your labour.

Comment: Where does 1.75ms come from? IIRC, pause between frames should be 3.5 characters long. So if you go with baudrate say 115200bps (not really fast at all), frame delay will be ~350us

Comment: that's what i thought, but there's a lower limit in the specs. Just check this: https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/serialcommunication.html

Answer (score 0):

Seeing an atmega8 is > 2€, your cost restriction is not that harsh., especially since you're also paying for the max485 (some 50 ct, I guess?). Also, your latency constraint/rate is very relaxed.

Drop the atmega, drop the max485, get one of the thousands of arm microcontrollers that come with CAN. Exactly that CAN was made for!

[Distributor MCU](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/STM32F042F6P6/497-17344-ND/5268189) product tables or octopart are your friends.

Comment: You may be right on the can part. Sadly, I got gifted about a hundred Atmegas and already own the MAX's. Sure, I could reinvest in another controllers. Could you please explain how can is more appropriate for the job, other than bandwidth?

Comment: Ease of programmin, cheapness of programmer, compilers that do not totally suck, lower power consumption,, especially better sleep modes,  but mostly:appropriateness for the job at hand are killer features of a different MCU than the terrible atmegas.

Comment: Can was literally designed for robust low-latency control applications within cars. How much better suited do you expect anything to be?

Comment: I really liked polling the same registers from different slave IDs over modbus. AFAIK CAN doesn't define that level of protocol. Using an MCP2515, should I still poll the sensor data with the master, or just proactively send it from the slaves whenever the measurement changes?

Comment: With CAN you send out the message when you need to. No need to poll. The receiver decides what messages they listen to.